# Number of antichains

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer. A family $A$ of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is an antichain if for any sets $X,Y\in A$, $X$ is not a subset of $Y$. What is the number of (i) antichains [(ii) non-isomorphic antichains resp.] on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of a fixed size $k$?

For e.g., $n=3$, some antichains of size $k=2$ are

\begin{align*}
A_1&=\{\{1\}, \{2,3\}\},\\
A_2&=\{\{2\}, \{1,3\}\},\\
A_3&=\{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}\}.
\end{align*}

$A_1$ and $A_2$ are isomorphic, and both of them are not isomorphic to $A_3$.

An antichain $A$ is isomorphic to another antichain $B$, if there exists a bijection $f$ from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that for any $X \subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $X$ is in $A$ if and only in $f(X)$ is in $B$, where $f(X)$ is defined to be $f(X):=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$.

Is this a solved question? I am solving a problem that I think is related to this question.
Please recommend papers/textbooks on this please. Thank you all.

Comment: Do you have a text that uses your definition of "isomorphism"?  It certainly isn't the [one I was expecting that makes your second question trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_isomorphism)

Comment: It is a standard definition used in hypergraphs, so i think you can find them in some of these texts, or alternatively, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph#Isomorphism,_symmetry,_and_equality